# Leaflet Interactive Mapping

Tags: leaflet, arcgis-online

I am trying to integrate an attribute query for an `L.esri.featurelayer` I'm currently using in one of my maps.

Currently I'm using this but it doesn't seem to work. The panel appears on the map but I can't seem to activate the selection of the various project types I'm trying to map out.

```
// Query to select project types 
var ProjectTyp = document.getElementById('ProjectTyp');

ProjectTyp.addEventListener('change', function(){
stops.setWhere(ProjectTyp.type);
});
```

Comment: This is unclear. What is "not working"? What is the `ProjectTyp` HTML element? Can we see a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?